# JPath for filtering properties not working

Tags: json, jsonpath, jpath

I'm new at JSONPath so I though maybe you could help me.

I've got the following JSON:

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "id":"recGyk2cLCzWoCFLj",
         "fields":{
            "Etapa":0,
            "Enviado por":"EFG",
            "Telemóvel":"919919919",
            "ID":1,
            "Nome":"Manuel"
         },
         "createdTime":"2022-01-31T20:40:45.000Z"
      },
      {
         "id":"rect2YP8RF2Jm88Cw",
         "fields":{
            "Etapa":0,
            "Enviado por":"CDE",
            "Telemóvel":"919919919",
            "ID":2,
            "Nome":"Maria"
         },
         "createdTime":"2022-01-31T20:40:45.000Z"
      },
      {
         "id":"rectoQCinQrYvMJFb",
         "fields":{
            "Etapa":0,
            "Enviado por":"ABC",
            "Telemóvel":"919919919",
            "ID":3,
            "Nome":"Joaquim"
         },
         "createdTime":"2022-01-31T20:40:45.000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the ID (the capital letter one) from the fields where 'Etapa==0'.

I've tried lots of combinations and `$.records[?(@.fields.Etapa==0)].fields.ID` seem like it could work but it doesn't.
When I try `$.records[?(@.id=="rectoQCinQrYvMJFb")].fields.ID` it works, so what could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: The expression was right, it needed quotes on the zero for the `$.records[?(@.fields.Etapa=="0")].fields.ID` expression as the field type was a string.

Comment: I'm not sure about jpath, but my implementation (.net) shows that your first query works fine.  You can try it at https://json-everything.net/json-path.

Comment: Oh... it looks like [jpath](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/dsm?topic=jpath-query) is a bit different than [JSON Path](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) ([spec repo](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base)).